# Build an IDT (INTERRUPT DESCRIPTOR TABLE) assembly AT&T intel 32 bits

Tags: assembly

I try to build an IDT, after sti execution, the code crashes !!

I have an error message : 
SingleStep CPU[1] Error : Processor Running

Remark: I use micro Atom with eclipse Helios, the assembly is AT&T

/****** ***************** New code  *******************/

New code after I found that the BIOS puts the atom in the protected mode (CR0.PE = 1)  and generates IDT/GDT :

The idea is just to use an ISR with APIC timer.

```
/*Change the address of idt_entries table */
fill_interrupt(ISR_Nbr,(unsigned int) isr33, 0x08, 0x8E);


static void fill_interrupt(unsigned char num, unsigned int base, unsigned short sel, unsigned char flags)
{
    unsigned short *Interrupt_Address;

    /*address = idt_ptr.base + num * 8 byte*/
    Interrupt_Address = (unsigned short *)(idt_ptr.base + num*8);

    *(Interrupt_Address) = base&0xFFFF;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = sel;
    *(Interrupt_Address+2) = (flags<<4)&0xFF00;
    *(Interrupt_Address+3) = (base>>16)&0xFFFF;

}
```

/****************************************End new code* ***********************************/

```
    idt_flush:
push %ebp   //save the context to swith back
mov %esp,%ebp

cli

mov $idt_ptr, %eax //Get the pointer to the IDT, passed as parameter
lidt    (%eax)         //Load the IDT pointer

sti

pop %ebp               //Return to the calling function
ret
```

What is wrong ???

see the rest of the code:

```
isr33:
    push %ebp   //save the context to swith back
    mov %esp,%ebp




    pop %ebp //Return to the calling function
    ret


static void init_idt()
{
    int iIndex;


    //Link the IDTR to IDT
    idt_ptr.limit = sizeof(idt_entry_t)*256-1;
    idt_ptr.base = (unsigned int)&idt_entries;

    idt_set_gate(0,(unsigned int) isr0, 0x00, 0xEE);
    for ( iIndex=1; iIndex<32; iIndex++)
    {
        idt_set_gate(iIndex,(unsigned int) isr0, 0x00, 0x00);

    }
    idt_set_gate(ISR_Nbr,(unsigned int) isr33, 0x00, 0xEE);

    //idt_flush((unsigned int)&idt_ptr);
    idt_flush();

}

static void idt_set_gate(unsigned char num, unsigned int base, unsigned short sel, unsigned char flags)
{
    idt_entries[num].base_lo = base&0xFFFF;
    idt_entries[num].base_hi = (base>>16)&0xFFFF;

    idt_entries[num].sel = sel;
    idt_entries[num].always0 = 0;

    idt_entries[num].flags = flags;
}



//IDT
struct idt_entry_struct
{
    unsigned short base_lo;
    unsigned short sel;
    unsigned char always0;
    unsigned char flags;
    unsigned short base_hi;
}__attribute__((packed));
typedef struct idt_entry_struct idt_entry_t;

//IDT register
struct idt_ptr_struct
{
    unsigned short limit;
    unsigned int base;
}__attribute__((packed));
typedef struct idt_ptr_struct idt_ptr_t;

//ISR number
int ISR_Nbr = 33;
```

Comment: We're going to need a bit more code than that. What does your actual IDT look like? Have you checked out http://wiki.osdev.org/IDT it's very helpful

Comment: @Earlz: I've just add the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, As I use a N450 Atom board, it has already a BIOS, the BIOS makes the IDT and GDT, all I have to do it is just to now where they are by reading thier adressess with : sidt (for IDT) and sgdt (for GDT).

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain why you set the selector values in IDT entries to 0? Aren't they supposed to be somewhat more meaningful?

I don't remember the details (and am too lazy to check the documentation at the moment), but set your access byte in IDT entries to 0x8E, not 0 or 0xEE. That should work. You can make it more complex later.

Finally, is isr33() a C function or assembly function? Does it save and restore segment registers and general-purpose registers? Show us the function.

Don't enable interrupts yet. First make sure that your isr33 functions properly when invoked through `INT 33`. Why? Having seen the above, I anticipate issues with the PIC configuration and handling and any hardware interrupt can just crash your code if the PIC is not programmed correctly.

Comment: The only difference between `0xEE` and `0x8E` is that `0xEE` can be called from ring 3. Setting it to 0 would disable the interrupt. But the selector value should definitely not be 0, it needs to be a code segment.

Comment: @Alex:--------1) I set the IDT0 to 31 to zero because i don't need them (I work on evaluation board Atom-32bits not on PC)
--------2)I put the ISR33 is assembly, The code rigth now crushes juste after STI, ii doesn't even point to ISR33
--------3)what do you mean by PIC ? I thought is just about IDT IDTR and ISR ...

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: Because i am working on Atom-Intel-32bits the mode is a Protected mode so no code segment is needed right ?

Comment: @mustapha: PIC = Programmable Interrupt Controller. There must be something, even if it's not a PIC, but LAPIC or LAPIC+something. I mean, the board is pretty much useless if the CPU can't get interrupts from other devices. IDT 0 through 31 are reserved for exceptions. Your code is crashing without giving you any clues precisely because you don't set up exception handlers. If you had them, you'd be able to see more (exception number and code, instruction that caused it, interrupt number). Anyway, if interrupts are disabled, can you successfully (w/o crashing/hanging) invoke isr33() with INT33?

Comment: @Alex : -----1)I don't get your point about the APIC? (Why i have to worry about the external interrupt) ------2)you are right i sort of crash the IDT0 to IDT31, but I m making a new IDT there is no soft on the board (except my code and the MicroC OS) ------3)I will do the test about the disable interrupt and Int 33.

Comment: @Alex : Anyway, if interrupts are disabled, can you successfully (w/o crashing/hanging) invoke isr33() with INT33? ===> No, if the interrupt is disable and I use int 33 the code crashes

Comment: Then there's a bug in isr33().

Comment: @Alex : hmmm, So the code is  : CLI=> LIDT(address of ptr) => STI =>crash, So why the problem is ISR33 ?? I don't even call it, just STI and the code crashes... I don't understand

Comment: @mustapha: STI causes a crash because either an interrupt occurs for which you don't have a valid IDT entry or because the ISR for that interrupt is buggy. If you had proper exception handlers, we could possibly figure it out, but you refuse implement them for whatever reasons you have. Fine, lets wander in the darkness. :)

Comment: @mustapha:  To figure out which one it is, I'm asking you to make your isr33() (or any other ISR, I don't really care which, isr255 is as good as almost any other) work when interrupts are disabled and when you invoke, say, isr33() by the INT 33 instruction. If that doesn't work, your isr33 (and any other ISRs you have) most likely have bugs. I want those bugs identified and fixed. Then it will be easier to fix any remaining interrupt-related issues. Face it, you don't know where the bug is. I don't know either, I don't see enough code.

Comment: @Alex: 10x alot for that, but hihihi it is not that i refuse to do it , it just i don't have enought experience, but i will try it tomorow or on monday, and i will let you know :)

Comment: @mustapha: just make an ISR for any int vector number from 32 to 255 work when invoked by INT that vector number. Begin with as simple ISR as just a single IRET instruction. That must work. If it doesn't, it means you still have garbage in CS or SS. Then extend the ISR to first save registers (DS, ES, FS, GS, EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, EDI, EBP) on the stack, then restore them from the stack, then do IRET. That must still work. Then make it call an arbitrary C function after it has saved the registers. That must still work. Do it step-by-step. Then make exception handlers out of it. And so on...

Comment: @mustapha You still use segments, they just correspond to GDT entries instead of addresses. If the OS set up the GDT for you, you could probably use `mov %cs, %eax` to get the current code segment and just use that.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw :  Good point, but I use MicroC OS and it doesn't set GDT.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw : AS there is no code on the Atom-32bit-Intel, how can ii be sure that I am in protected mode ?

Comment: @mustapha I assumed you were since you were using `esp` and `ebp` (you only need `sp` and `bp` in real mode, since it uses 16 bit addressing). If you aren't sure, use `mov %cr0, %eax`, and bit 0 of the result will be set for protected mode and clear for real mode.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw :  Yes you are right, I use esp and ebp, and the CR0.PE =1,add to that the BIOS (on the card) generate IDT and GDT (I checked with sidt/sgdt), so  have their addresses and size. But right now even after I creat an ISR (33), it still crashes when I use "Int $33" !!! (see above for the code of the ISR and how I linkde to 33)

Comment: @mustapha: ISRs must return with iret, not ret.

Comment: @mustapha: it definitely can.

Comment: @mustapha: what is in the segment and general-purpose registers before you invoke int 33? Also, what is in your GDT?